# Contract call not returning?

Tags: solidity, web3js

For some reason all my functions are able to return my calls except this one particular function. I call it using Truffle.

```
async function asdf() {
let contractInstance = await MyContract.at('0x...')
let currentSupply = await contractInstance.getCurrentSupply()
console.log(`Current Supply: ${currentSupply}`);
}
```

When I return it, it doesn't show up as `0`. I put `return 1` just to see if it would even return anything, but it's still returning `0`

```
function getCurrentSupply() constant returns (uint256) {
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure "1" is a uint256. Have you tried "returns (uint)" instead?

Comment: `uint` is an alias for `uint256`. And `1` is definitely a valid value for `uint256`.

Comment: Hey, 
It would be better if you share some snippet from your code, but you can change MyContractInstance.getCurrentSupply() to MyContractInstance.getCurrentSupply.call()  
I am not sure but it can be the case